# How to do data validation in an elegant way when write C++ functions?

Tags: c++, styles

I am a novice of C++, I don't know how to check if the input is valid in an good way, could anyone help me?
E.g.
I have a function,

```
int foo(int p, int r) {
  if (p < r) {
    .....
  }
}
```

in this function, p must be smaller than r; but when p >= r, what should I return? or throw an exception like using Java?

Thank you!

Comment: If the values being passed in are programmatically computed, use `assert`; if they're user/file input, throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a decision you need to make. The question is, "How do I deal with invalid arguments?"

Answers could be:

1. Ignore them. Make the code work regardless. This would mean that you need to consider what values to return when invalid data is provided, like in your example code.
2. Make your code yell out, so you know when it happens and can fix it then and there.

   - An assert is the simplest.
   - Exceptions are another choice.

When in doubt, choose the simplest approach for your current needs because you cannot reliably predict what your future needs will be. So in this case, I'd go with an assert.

The reason is that the best way to solve a problem is to prevent it happening in the first place. Asserts go a long way towards ensuring the problem does not happen, because they force you, the developer to deal with them immediately.

Answer (score 1):

These are those decisions that you make based on the logic of your application. In c++ `0` signifies `false` and anything other than 0  signifies `true`. Or otherwise you could `assert` statement in c++. The choice is left to you. You could incorporate this logic into your application to actually handle situations that you have mentioned. But a definitive answer to your question always

Comment: Actually any value other than 0, greater or lower, signifies `true`.

Comment: @twain249: Agreed. Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about good ways to catch these errors, Asserts are pretty helpful.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/

```
int Foo(int p, int r)
{
   assert (p < r);
   if (p < r)
   { ... }
}
```

When you run through that code, your code will yell at you, and you know the data was messed up. You can even jump in and see why it's wrong.

There is plenty of other error handling in c++. I believe Try/Catch statements were added many years back, if you prefer those.

Comment: `assert` is not a replacement for try/catch; the two are orthogonal in their use-cases.